# Java - Calculate second coordinates from a given coordinates, bearing, and distance

Tags: java, algorithm, distance, haversine

I found the formula to calculate the second coordinates [here](http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#LL). But when I converted it to Java, the result is not as I expected.

```
private Point get(double lat1, double lon1, double tc, int d) {
    double lat = Math.asin(
                          Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(d) 
                        + Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(d) * Math.cos(tc)
                        );

    double dlon= Math.atan2(
                          Math.sin(tc) * Math.sin(d) * Math.cos(lat1)
                        , Math.cos(d) - Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(lat));
    double lon = ((lon1 - dlon + Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI)) - Math.PI;

    return new Point(lat, lon);
}
```

I tested the code above with simple case such as get(50, 10, 0, 0). So expected the result will be as same as the first point, but this is the result I got:

```
Lat: 1.4432701894877245, lon: -3.8108244707674395
```

Am I using correct formula to calculate second coordinates?

[EDIT]
Here is the formula that I try to convert to java code

```
 lat =asin(sin(lat1)*cos(d)+cos(lat1)*sin(d)*cos(tc))
 dlon=atan2(sin(tc)*sin(d)*cos(lat1),cos(d)-sin(lat1)*sin(lat))
 lon=mod( lon1-dlon +pi,2*pi )-pi
```

Comment: the unit of tc is radian and d is km. I don't think the primary type will effect the result in this algorithm.

Comment: I think something wrong with your formula because `cos(d)` do not have any sense.

Comment: @talex I included the formula that I used for the calculation

Comment: I think d is probably in radians, too. Probably the distance divided by the Earth's circumference, multiplied by 2π.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou since my distance input is 0, so I think it is not the case as well. But I just convert distance to radian, and it doesn't work too

Comment: `lat1` and `lon1` must be in radians.

Comment: Try `0.5, 0.1, 0, 0` as input.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, your formulas expect that the latitude, longitude, true course, and distance are all in radians.

If you want to pass in latitude, longitude, true course in degrees, and distance in nautical miles, you will need to do the following conversion below any math:

```
// convert to radians
lat1 = lat1 * Math.PI / 180; 
lon1 = lon1 * Math.PI / 180; 
tc = tc * Math.PI / 180;
d = (Math.PI / (180*60)) * d;
```

and then convert your latitude and longitude back from radians to degrees:

```
// convert to degrees
lat = lat * 180 / Math.PI;
lon = lon * 180 / Math.PI;
```

However, two other notes:

1) java.awt.Point (not clear this is what you're using) can only hold integers; you might want to use Point2D.Double instead; and

2) Distance should also be measured including fractions of either nautical miles or radians, so should be a double.

With those edits, get(50, 10, 0, 0) will work.  As will the worked example from your page for a waypoint 100nm from LAX on the 66 degree radial - get(33.95, 118.4, 66, 100) (remember that minutes are converted into fractional degrees) returns 34.6141 lat and 116.5499 lon, matching 34d 37m and 116d 33m.

Comment: Why not use [`Math.toRadians`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toRadians-double-) and [`Math.toDegrees`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toDegrees-double-)?

Comment: Because I was staring at the formula web page Hien linked to, and it had the radian <--> degree conversions there.